# Downloading jdk using powershell

Tags: java, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to download the java jdk using powershell scripting as given in the link below

http://poshcode.org/4224

. Here as the author has specified , if I Change the source url where the latest jdk is present 
i.e.,

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-windows-x64.exe

the content is not getting loaded , only about 6KB gets downloaded . I have a doubt , whether the download limit in powershell script is only 6KB?

Here is the code :

```
$source = "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-windows-i586.exe"
      $destination = "C:\Download\Java\jdk-7u60-windows-i586.exe"
      $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
      $client.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

Comment: The author is not downloading from the oracle site probably...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On inspecting the session on oracle site the following cookie catches attention: `oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie`. With that in mind you can run the following code:

```powershell
$source = "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-windows-i586.exe"
$destination = "C:\Download\Java\jdk-7u60-windows-i586.exe"
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$cookie = "oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
$client.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, $cookie) 
$client.downloadFile($source, $destination)
```

Comment: `Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:1
+ $client.downloadFile($source, $destination)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
`

Comment: Hey @MatasVaitkevicius, it would be better if you raise this a separate question - the original post is nearly 6 years old...

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: here's the reason for your problem: you can't directly download the file without **accepting the terms** before.

I'm using the following script to download files. It's working with HTTP as well as with FTP. It might be a little overkill for your task because it also shows the download progress but you can trim it untill it fits your needs.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $url,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $localFile = (Join-Path $pwd.Path $url.SubString($url.LastIndexOf('/'))) 
)

begin {
    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $Global:downloadComplete = $false

    $eventDataComplete = Register-ObjectEvent $client DownloadFileCompleted `
        -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadFileComplete `
        -Action {$Global:downloadComplete = $true}
    $eventDataProgress = Register-ObjectEvent $client DownloadProgressChanged `
        -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged `
        -Action { $Global:DPCEventArgs = $EventArgs }    
}

process {
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Downloading file' -Status $url
    $client.DownloadFileAsync($url, $localFile)

    while (!($Global:downloadComplete)) {                
        $pc = $Global:DPCEventArgs.ProgressPercentage
        if ($pc -ne $null) {
            Write-Progress -Activity 'Downloading file' -Status $url -PercentComplete $pc
        }
    }

    Write-Progress -Activity 'Downloading file' -Status $url -Complete
}

end {
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadFileComplete
    $client.Dispose()
    $Global:downloadComplete = $null
    $Global:DPCEventArgs = $null
    Remove-Variable client
    Remove-Variable eventDataComplete
    Remove-Variable eventDataProgress
    [GC]::Collect()    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code , but unfortunately it is not downloading the complete exe, only 6KB is getting downloaded . The url I am using is  : http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-windows-x64.exe

Comment: This is what I'm getting on openning the URL:Sorry!
In order to download products from Oracle Technology Network you must agree to the OTN license terms.
Be sure that...
Your browser has "cookies" and JavaScript enabled.
You clicked on "Accept License" for the product you wish to download.
You attempt the download within 30 minutes of accepting the license.
From here you can go...
 Back to Previous Page
 Site Map
 OTN Homepage

Comment: So here's the reason for your problem: you can't directly download the file without accepting the terms before.

Comment: Those two parameters are set in the IE browser dude , even then I am getting the same thing, can you once verify if possible try to download jdk from oracle site please, then later I will recheck the problem from my end...

Comment: Same problem here. Download via browser works fine but the script doesn't work.

Comment: So what to do now? how can anybody download from oracle site?

Comment: But now I'm sure that the problem is the terms agreement. If you save the error website it has is exactly the size of the file you are downloading. You can even rename the downloaded file from .exe to .html and open it in your browser.

Comment: Got an idea but it's dirty. You can use a tool like JMeter to record a macro of HTTP-calls leading you over accepting the terms to the download and try to reproduce the path by directly sending the HTTP requests. No idea whether it works.

Answer (score 1):

After needing this script for a platform installer that required the JDK as a dependency:

```
<# Config #>
$DownloadPageUri = 'https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html';
$JavaVersion = '8u201';

<# Build the WebSession containing the proper cookie 
   needed to auto-accept the license agreement. #>
$Cookie=New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Cookie; 
$Cookie.Domain='oracle.com';
$Cookie.Name='oraclelicense';
$Cookie.Value='accept-securebackup-cookie'; 
$Session= `
   New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession;
$Session.Cookies.Add($Cookie);

<# Fetch the proper Uri and filename from the webpage. #>
$JdkUri = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DownloadPageUri -WebSession $Session -UseBasicParsing).RawContent `
    -split "`n" | ForEach-Object { `
        If ($_ -imatch '"filepath":"(https://[^"]+)"' { `
            $Matches[1] `
        } `
    } | Where-Object { `
        $_ -like "*-$JavaVersion-windows-x64.exe" `
    }[0];
If ($JdkUri -imatch '/([^/]+)$') { 
    $JdkFileName=$Matches[1];
}

<# Use a try/catch to catch the 302 moved temporarily 
   exception generated by oracle from the absance of
   AuthParam in the original URL, piping the exception's
   AbsoluteUri to a new request with AuthParam returned
   from Oracle's servers.  (NEW!) #>

try { 
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $JdkUri -WebSession $Session -OutFile "$JdkFileName"
} catch { 
    $authparam_uri = $_.Exception.Response.Headers.Location.AbsoluteUri;
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $authparam_uri -WebSession $Session -OutFile "$JdkFileName"
}
```

Works in PowerShell 6.0 (Hello 2019!)  Required a minor fixup to the regex and the way the -imatch line scan happened.  Workaround to follow 302 redirects was located here:  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2896 (302 redirect workaround by fcabralpacheco readapted to get Oracle downloads working again !

This solution downloads 8u201 for Windows x64 automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted comment is not working anymore and I cannot comment, I will leave my method here. I modified @steve-coleman's answer by making it scan the page for download links that start with `https` instead of `http`. Also I needed to modify `$Response` to have a `-UseBasicParsing` flag as I was using a headless Windows Server. All in all the script I used was:

```
$DownloadPageUri = 'http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html'
$JavaVersion = '8u192'

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DownloadPageUri -UseBasicParsing

$JreUri = @($Response.RawContent -split "`n" | ForEach-Object {If ($_ -imatch '"filepath":"(https://[^"]+)"') {$Matches[1]}} | Where-Object {$_ -like "*-$JavaVersion-windows-x64.tar.gz"})
If (-Not $JreUri.Count -eq 1) {
    throw ('Expected to retrieve only one URI but got {0}' -f $JreUri.Count)
}

If ($JreUri[0] -imatch '/([^/]+)$') {
    $JreFileName = $Matches[1]
}
$JreFileName = 'jre-windows-x64.tar.gz'

If (-Not (Test-Path -Path "$PSScriptRoot\$JreFileName") -Or -Not (Test-Path -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Java-$JavaVersion.tag")) {
    $Cookie  = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Cookie
    $Cookie.Domain = 'oracle.com'
    $Cookie.Name   = 'oraclelicense'
    $Cookie.Value  = 'accept-securebackup-cookie'
    $Session = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
    $Session.Cookies.Add($Cookie)
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $JreUri[0] -WebSession $Session -OutFile "$PSScriptRoot\$JreFileName"
    New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Java-$JavaVersion.tag" -ItemType File | Out-Null
}
```

As usual, YMMV, especially if Oracle change their website.

Answer (score 0):

I modified Robert Smith's answer as follows to get SDK 8u211

```
<# Config #>
$DownloadPageUri = 'https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html';
$JavaVersion = '8u211';
<# Build the WebSession containing the proper cookie
   needed to auto-accept the license agreement. #>

$Cookie=New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Cookie;
$Cookie.Domain='oracle.com';
$Cookie.Name='oraclelicense';
$Cookie.Value='accept-securebackup-cookie';
$Session= `
   New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession;
$Session.Cookies.Add($Cookie);

# Fetch the proper Uri and filename from the webpage. #>
$i = 0
#echo $i
#$rc = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DownloadPageUri -WebSession $Session     -UseBasicParsing).RawContent
#echo $rc >> Oracle.html
#-split "`n" | ForEach-Object { `
$JdkUri = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DownloadPageUri -WebSession $Session -UseBasicParsing).RawContent `
-split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object { `
    #echo "$i : $_" >> Oracle.html
    #echo "$i"
    #$i++
    If ($_ -imatch '"filepath":"(https://[^"]+)"') { `
        $Matches[1] `
    } `
} | Where-Object { `
    $_ -like "*-$JavaVersion-windows-x64.exe" `
}[0];
If ($JdkUri -imatch '/([^/]+)$') {
    $JdkFileName=$Matches[1];
}
echo "JdkUri: $JdkUri" >> out.txt

<# Use a try/catch to catch the 302 moved temporarily
   exception generated by oracle from the absance of
   AuthParam in the original URL, piping the exception's
   AbsoluteUri to a new request with AuthParam returned
   from Oracle's servers.  (NEW!) #>

try {
    echo "In the try" >> out.txt
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $JdkUri -WebSession $Session -OutFile "$JdkFileName"
} catch {
    echo "In the catch" >> out.txt
    $authparam_uri = $_.Exception.Response.Headers.Location.AbsoluteUri;
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $authparam_uri -WebSession $Session -OutFile "$JdkFileName"
}
```

Had to change the line
    -split "`n" | ForEach-Object {`
to
    -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object { `

And the line
    If ($_ -imatch '"filepath":"(https://[^"]+)"' { 
`to
    If ($_ -imatch '"filepath":"(https://[^"]+)"') {`

But in the jkd-8u211-windows-x64.exe file I see

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitForm()
{
    var hash = location.hash;
    if (hash) {
        if(hash.indexOf("#") == -1){
            hash="#"+hash
        }
        document.myForm.action = document.myForm.action+hash;
    }
    document.myForm.submit();
}
</script><head><base target="_self"></head><body onLoad="submitForm()"><noscript>       <p>JavaScript is required. Enable JavaScript to use OAM Server.</p></noscript><form   action="https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp" method="post" name="myForm"> <!------------ DO NOT REMOVE -------------><!----- loginform renderBrowserView -----><!-- Required for SmartView Integration --><input type="hidden" name="bmctx" value="05C65B855F507509F2A50E4187F746B908003F815E8CAC65124394831AC5D9EF"><input type="hidden" name="contextType" value="external"><input type="hidden" name="username" value="string"><input type="hidden" name="contextValue" value="%2Foam"><input type="hidden" name="password" value="secure_string"><input type="hidden" name="challenge_url" value="https%3A%2F%2Flogin.oracle.com%2Fmysso%2Fsignon.jsp"><input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="-7095362132919578964"><input type="hidden" name="authn_try_count" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="OAM_REQ" value="VERSION_4~FWMjicP9PEQpljiEhsObqw9ylPjCAidBVTTJxhmD1hxQnGA4pyWKyCqsJWbqRCHi7qV9ZGSvNoA5t9c33sgIg2B%2bVMyE%2b7Ev3v%2f0UWTE5TDtvGOxisL8d7gDA5piF4HZHubed6GfNVCktpGfz0y7KW0roRz3%2b58adfBEomJffDOl1UAkCDbV%2b7712R6CjE6nfODUMJTFUJ6nc9Zq6%2fuooydHQx9GjTeD6RBSlDo2L2b0KDi5g1exggoqrUMintE3QRbymUgvxkJyVAoxC%2bo8xLDF4EOICI0vkYnovHUNN%2bNoiQLGWXv1ryOuFy9FIebX%2bA5uxiDbulaRSDQcGO1LefWYF%2bBP7Vo3wRcNb%2bgc8J9%2fRjGVlKQSETLkUXd%2fo0U7cEPFSrq1qOmE6B7yKkB3zFnIsxHELMwdhVD5WJ95xebDem9xlhv61ImKJH3JdrnnDYZ3e3S1v90epLpFQyG1BExZxc%2fVLQZt%2bAexfGNstpqmlCFnfuC4Xudh0omOLAz5ZCdeWReNh0rC%2f0jXLEAkq6DghomBCNI5pGVKH1CVgb13HZOS%2boOuCaz4nw%2fAkkS949FW8Mzj0P9Cll7AlbTwfLuWnc%2bY8r%2f4bKD7X4WqVo%2f%2bcuS43eTIg%2fxPsoEIedsoixUcnZAfChgbZP%2fJPaLEinf0iR0G%2fy9IzTwPiIx8u6NZmk7Uec6GcGH3q4%2b9sI6D3mcBFJQIAfIxE89v9Nu5%2f62tDAIhD8I4%2fNfwC2uhixRGTHwLA7Fzc5qXRJ7JpaI5ogDbko%2fiSjIajClXUzIwTICAuzZvSOk8uAJfQQusjDVLVdEpVphg3fujGGcWgyvko%2bqQadGQcDWAxxWFMihNQRFpFeJTPaGVFnJfwy6M0tA3KA8HS%2bTA4rTinZyh04Tm1skPHNKi8VASeNSU5xEzdVa%2fKhJhjV4SvNyCwl3gIT%2ba%2b16OFrn3zCSy%2bC4sljmU9zJRH%2f3Bcj8JWnoKIuw51uh6k7OCt7NDoplaAj9YujMm%2bPGyicQv2mPe8vfl1VH9KyLuOYuQERuNNdA%2bdwIXBnKxA3ySClPikrgwRjTRO0bKjBeyDMIjfi4UwNNwb6Mi8K2QYW8Ydt0yJvLnJxLx0JviP1p8PqxrlAMNvHcle04%2bDN1ahBSxYsVvt3fbYkN0KlySSiGyhrixoPVkZR2Rhbkfm8o352YKaibkKIFPyHmTGCGmhr8kgH87qc1uIV7YXymRHfEWej2ZEFIvPEjj8M7%2fCllJ1%2fVEzj%2f1oHvBaPJKsyKt2BguiTnvJ47k9ijEhKluLpBvY5i7dJdvhlzziY1sQ8Iik42PNqVzVL8WIIe6qttdZfl6Hbmm9ZDJDRQAkeFNmWZ4aSicSFZzoEIRB5sa%2b9nSmIHEgE9umTJAqhsiEBeEYtx6quE6BISxCXQQXBIZEwLQ7Dsx1qRgqrIDN2EwjBTO5S9A1JkcR089pnkcHbZUmlSnohyhwizYAegk5te78cq59dVl6e0QyOBzThP0hNrMitYe3KW7yJA5zcqNAqMEsuFDLmviNeKKKCcFlpw4l8H%2fMinEt%2bjM0AuDStGxf1ve3bzkWTtu6GLjGQFCf4Zlq7Q%2f12eMCype4lCnFwL8OA7J7LakMUK8miUiiEgJDfcLsRYDVa4amcR6uUo2E3GueUa4KXXH6XZQg%2fvH6JmzvP%2bLIKx%2fyMWf6JuKdi6w6P34VTBPLi1o9rQVTeIMQB0NsvQWowWcZEm1eGLC1Q%2fVJFMUHTCF9S75hL%2bYSve%2blE2JKf4Fbxp%2fAEGsuHmfRNu8lWHzaNuuFRZwl0mt8OnnmPAhOYpb1fvqkGLQfFRRYF1H7S1zFcTGeFalXa9FeuAQ31xglHgoXYni6TJOSQWbKAEiyh6YjwPza2U0hcaS%2fLbJwblHbhx8dko3My7kED75iKKmfUsvWO%2fxE93ngbP%2bNC8vs7KVzKyJhoKamHYykXfqWCWlCAz%2fyzo2GgU1ZAIdTHQOrysMnTIZxQvm9oOK8egdTbrweyHjsLYNGvA8LbmutI8%2fbtAD5BS9IE02qL2YtmI3nT39srKW%2b8JEP727dtLDGPaFJGDmfszhXZu1elSKEOUa62O8QoIjt5znJaVfJgh3sNrvj6VgGj3WGZf5EVMeD6LUdrQEtv8G3ZIkL1p%2f3qBSlgDjEPjDcTUJtEYNjuly7FNyBq2ZEgwvIjXIB8Q8nId%2b1QPOygTfkM5gqFlK2tG0sRpZEIh6J9Ov1IsgKBTBvfGvGuwI3REk2WXMkt78l7JrS3zvQoXpbM4e724JosN7LnrLQ%2bxn%2f6Ofy4RGNDza9FpGkcXea9%2b5%2fnNEKDNaYl3hZiTS2YxYTDFSKkotkadA3BJBse9dMF1cC5bj3IKgiNrTgSpHOvZbIEVi7bRJg7x66lzWWuellSEd%2bZYpIdxdBqUGrF7KehTh%2fHsjG5T5678e%2fuT8Uvm9S7bmE6xY3tBlQ2aO5FKWIA%3d%3d"><input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en"><input type="hidden" name="resource_url" value="https%253A%252F%252Fedelivery.oracle.com%252Fakam%252Fotn%252Fjava%252Fjdk%252F8u211-b12%252F478a62b7d4e34b78b671c754eaaf38ab%252Fjdk-8u211-windows-x64.exe"></form></body>    </html>
```

Not sure what to do next.
Also added a bit of debug jazz like
    #echo "$i : $_" >> Oracle.html
...

Answer (score -1):

I got this here and all credit goes to him.... 
http://dille.name/blog/2016/06/21/running-minecraft-in-a-windows-container-using-docker/

https://github.com/nicholasdille/docker

It works and downloads the Java files.

```
$DownloadPageUri = 'http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html'
$JavaVersion = '8u172'

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DownloadPageUri

$JreUri = @($Response.RawContent -split "`n" | ForEach-Object {If ($_ -imatch '"filepath":"(http://[^"]+)"') {$Matches[1]}} | Where-Object {$_ -like "*-$JavaVersion-windows-x64.tar.gz"})
If (-Not $JreUri.Count -eq 1) {
    throw ('Expected to retrieve only one URI but got {0}' -f $JreUri.Count)
}

If ($JreUri[0] -imatch '/([^/]+)$') {
    $JreFileName = $Matches[1]
}
$JreFileName = 'jre-windows-x64.tar.gz'

If (-Not (Test-Path -Path "$PSScriptRoot\$JreFileName") -Or -Not (Test-Path -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Java-$JavaVersion.tag")) {
    $Cookie  = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Cookie
    $Cookie.Domain = 'oracle.com'
    $Cookie.Name   = 'oraclelicense'
    $Cookie.Value  = 'accept-securebackup-cookie'
    $Session = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
    $Session.Cookies.Add($Cookie)
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $JreUri[0] -WebSession $Session -OutFile "$PSScriptRoot\$JreFileName"
    New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Java-$JavaVersion.tag" -ItemType File | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: I am not sure who down voted this. but it works fine. Check the DownloadPageUri, javaversion, and JavaVersion-windows-x64.tar.gz are still valid. If oracle changes anything this will stop working.

Comment: Try setting $JavaVersion = '8u191', This is going to break every time they update their version info.